# Ubuntu installation through VM for Hadoop environmental setup

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine

I'm a newbie to **Hadoop** domain. I want to know about the system requirements for setting up the hadoop environment. My laptop has **4GB RAM, 1TB HDD with Windows 10** OS. Is it possible to install **Ubuntu** through **VM** with my **4GB RAM** size? or Should i extend my RAM size?

Answer (score 1):

At least 8GB RAM but I would recommend 16GB since you need some for Windows and all your office tools. https://fr.hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/1/

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to install Ubuntu through VM with my 4GB RAM size?

Yes, it is, but you need to actually understand each of the JVM options and how to tune them.

Running DataNode + NameNode + ResourceManager + NodeManager each with a default of 1GB of memory needed will not work with your current memory space.

---

The Hortonworks and Cloudera VM's recommend 8GB minimum **for the VM alone** (which means you need more on your host machine), however, those VMs also include Hive, Spark, HBase, Oozie, etc.